# Import error: ImportError: No module named requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, urllib

I am new to python and webscraping. I am using linux mint 18.2 with python 2.7.12.
I am trying to import and eventually execute urllib.request with beautifulsoup but eventually failed till now. I have installed,after stackoverflow reference, requests module using - sudo apt-get install python-requests. Which ran successfully.

So, please see all the trial and errors I carried out (unsuccessfully until now) and help me execute urllib.request. Thanks!

```
>>> import bs4
>>> pip install urllib
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import urlihb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import urlihb
ImportError: No module named urlihb
>>> import urllib
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen as newreq

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen as newreq
ImportError: No module named request
>>> import urllib2
>>> from urllib2.request import urlopen as newreq

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib2.request import urlopen as newreq
ImportError: No module named request
>>> sudo pip install request
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sudo install request
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sudp pip install requests
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sudo pip install requests
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sudo install requests
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import urllib2
>>> from urllib2.request import urlopen as newreq

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib2.request import urlopen as newreq
ImportError: No module named request
>>> from urllib2.requests import urlopen as newreq

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib2.requests import urlopen as newreq
ImportError: No module named requests
>>> import urllib3.request import urlopen as newreq
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import urllib2.request

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2.request
ImportError: No module named request
>>> urllib2.requests

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib2.requests
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'requests'
>>> import urllib2.requests

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2.requests
ImportError: No module named requests
>>> import urllib2.request

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2.request
ImportError: No module named request
>>> import urllib.reques

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.reques
ImportError: No module named reques
>>> import urllib.request

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
>>> import beautifulsoup

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    import beautifulsoup
ImportError: No module named beautifulsoup
>>> import beautifullsoup as bs4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    import beautifullsoup as bs4
ImportError: No module named beautifullsoup
>>> import bs4
>>> import urllib.request

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
>>> import urllib2.request

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2.request
ImportError: No module named request
>>> import urllib.requests

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.requests
ImportError: No module named requests
>>> import urllib2.requests

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2.requests
ImportError: No module named requests
>>>
```

Comment: a) You can't run `pip` in the interpreter like this. Run it in your system shell! b) you have to type command and name properly, without spelling mistakes.

Comment: So when you want to use pip to install new stuff, you have to do it in cmd, preferably as an administrator (otherwise `Access is Denied` might pop up)

Answer (score 1):

all you need is : "import urllib.request"

after you ran "pip install urllib "

Comment: 1)sudo apt-install python-pip;2)pip install upgrade pip; 3)sudo pip install setuptools ; 4) sudo pip install bs4-this is the sequence of commands I executed.Success failure in importing urllib.request I will check later and update.Thanks!

Comment: I tried testing whether my suo pip install requests is working well when I use import requests in python IDLE(2.7.12). It threw this error:-Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 80
    RequestsDependencyWarning)
RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.13.1) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!

Comment: Another error was also thrown successively(Please help me)-Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    from urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name DependencyWarning